# Force SSL on Amazon S3

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-s3

Is it possible (via IAM, bucket policy, or otherwise) to force Amazon S3 to **only** serve content over HTTPS/SSL and deny all regular, unencrypted HTTP access?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I believe this can be achieved using a bucket policy. Deny all HTTP requests to the bucket in question using the condition `aws:SecureTransport: false`.
The following is not tested but it should give you an idea of how to set it up for your case.

```
{
    "Statement":[
        {
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect":"Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
            "Condition":{
                "Bool":
                { "aws:SecureTransport": false }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, that is, I can still access http://my.website.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com, which is the S3 endpoint

Comment: Wow, this actually worked really well. Much simpler than the AWS Policy Generator. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here you allow your incoming traffic but refuse the non SSL one. If you want to go back just remove the 2<sup>nd</sup> statement:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::yourbucketnamehere/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::yourbucketnamehere/*",
            "Condition":{
                "Bool":
                { "aws:SecureTransport": false }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Don't forget to put your bucket name at `yourbucketnamehere`.

Now you need to install a SSL certificate. [All the information can be found here](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/08/redirect-domain-https-amazon-cloudfront/).

Comment: I tried that; it simply blocks every access.