# Is the S3 Protocol encrypted in transmission when using the SDK?

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

if I'm using the [AmazonS3Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html) to put and fetch files, is my connection encrypted? This seems basic, but my googling seems to return things about encrypting the S3 storage and not whether the transmission from this client is secure. If it's not secure is there a setting to make it secure?

Comment: Some quick searching suggests that [it defaults to HTTPS unless you give it an HTTP url to connect to](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html#getProtocol--).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Amazon S3 endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region) support both HTTP and HTTPS. It is recommended that you communicate via HTTPS to ensure your data is encrypted in transit.

You can also create a Bucket Policy that enforces communication via HTTPS. See:

- Stackoverflow: [Force SSL on Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21087474/174777)
- Sample policy: [s3BucketPolicyEncryptionSSL.json](https://gist.github.com/steinsag/bcc29d9c304ed4925e76)

Comment: huh, for some reason I thought s3 had its own protocol, probably because occasionally I've seen `s3://` uri's, which would generally mean use the s3 protocol... so I presumed that s3 sdk was using something other than http(s). since I can't find any reference to said protocol, I'm guessing it's just a shorthand used by some clients reference the endpoint.

Comment: The `s3://` prefix is used when referring to Amazon S3 buckets within the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), Amazon EMR and some other services, just to differentiate it from files on the local disk volume.